# Centering a logo in the header

Tags: css, wordpress, header, safari

I want to center my header logo on [this page](http://www.beau-velo.com/WordPress).

I tried:

```
.site-header {
    margin-left: 30px;
    margin-right: 30px;
    padding: 20px 0;
    text-align:center; 
}
.site-header hgroup {
    display: inline;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right:auto;
}
```

And this is the original code:

```
.site-header {
    margin-left: 30px;
    margin-right: 30px;
    padding: 20px 0;
}
.site-header hgroup {
    display: inline;
    float: left;
}
.site-header .site-title {
    display: inline;
    float: left;
    margin-right: 10px;
}
.site-header .site-title a, .site-header .site-title img {
    display: block;
}
.site-header #site-description {
    display: inline;
    float: left;
    font-size: 10px;
    font-weight: 600;
    padding: 20px 0;
}
```

By the way I have an other problem, the logo (.png image) are not always displayed by Safari (Chrome is OK), sometimes you have to resize the window or clic on menu item to make it appear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.site-header hgroup {
        display: block;
        margin: 0 auto;
        float: none;
        width: 120px;
}`